# Asp Net Core Identity как отображать данные пользователя в представлении?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

Я сделал приложение с регистрацией и авторизацией. После регистрации пользователя перекидывает на страницу с настройками профиля. Там идёт редактирование данных юзера. А потом кидает на главную страницу где должны выводится в нужных местах данные(емейл,телефон,ник и пр.).

Как мне сделать отображение данных в представлении?

Comment: В каких представлениях и какие данные?

Comment: Представление главной страницы,вообще не важно какой. Данные из таблицы,связанной с таблицей IdentityUser. В которой помимо стандартных свойств Identity User я добавил несколько своих.

Comment: вот все подробно расписано... https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/user-management-in-aspnet-core-mvc/